# Extracting all values of a subject attribute in a certificate

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, certificate, cryptoapi

I'm currently using [`CertGetNameString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to extract the values for each subject attribute like so:

```cpp
CertGetNameString(pCertificate,
                  CERT_NAME_ATTR_TYPE,
                  0,
                  szOID_ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT_NAME,
                  buf,
                  _countof(buf));
```

However some certificates I've found have multiple values for the organizational unit name (OU) and `CertGetNameString` can only read the first. For instance this is the subject of an Adobe certificate:

```
CN = Adobe Systems, Incorporated
OU = Acrobat Engineering
OU = Digital ID Class 3 - Microsoft Software Validation v2
O = Adobe Systems, Incorporated
L = San Jose
S = California
C = US
```

How can I read all values for the OU (and other) attribute(s) using CryptoAPI?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, found the solution. The correct API to use is `CertNameToStr`, like so:

```cpp
    CertNameToStr(X509_ASN_ENCODING,
                  &pCertificate->pCertInfo->Subject,
                  CERT_X500_NAME_STR,
                  buf,
                  _countof(buf));
```

It will return a string such as:

```
C=US, S=California, L=San Jose, O="Adobe Systems, Incorporated", OU=Digital ID Class 3 - Microsoft Software Validation v2, OU=Acrobat Engineering, CN="Adobe Systems, Incorporated"
```

Which can then be parsed if individual attribute values are required.